# Is it possible to completely hide files created in Android apps?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm developing an Android app that uses a camera to take photos (like the custom camera in [the Android camera guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)). I'm saving the photo using the Context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) method to associate the photo with the app, and the photos don't appear to show up in the Gallery (that's good).

However if I remove the microSD card and look through it on my computer, I can find the photos under Android/data/com.example.MyApp/files/Pictures/my_picture_folder/. Is it possible to save these photos in a way that they are completely inaccessible outside of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The photos need to be saved somewhere, so there is no avoiding finding them when you put the card in your computer. However you could

- A. Obscure them, by renaming them from say .jpg to .dat
- B. Encrypt them, and save them encrypted file on the sd card. Then decrypt them each time they are needed (obviously with the downside of speed and battery life)

Comment: Thanks! I think changing the extension to .dat should be adequate protection.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to save these photos in a way that they are completely inaccessible outside of my app?

You can save the images to internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). That will prevent most people from accessing them. However:

- Rooted device users can get at anything they want on the device
- If the user thinks that the user owns the photos, the user may point a shotgun in your general direction for hiding those photos

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used suggestions from both answers, but I unfortunately cannot choose both as the correct one. And the user will be able to access the photos from within the app, but I don't want anyone else using their device to be able to find them outside of it.